# Working on Gmaps distance API, have installed package, the error shows could not find function "gmapsdistance"

Tags: r

Using the code to install the package on

```
install.packages("gmapsdistance", dependencies = TRUE)
```

when I provide the code it returns a error

```
results = gmapsdistance(origin = "origin location", destination = "destination location", mode = "Walking")
```

the error I get is

> could not find function "gmapsdistance"

What am I missing out here?

Comment: have you loaded the library - `library(gmapsdistance)` ?

Comment: yes used the code - install.packages("gmapsdistance", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: but have you loaded the library - `library(gmapsdistance)` ? After installing, you need to load the library to be able to use it in your R session.

Comment: Yes have loaded the library- library("gmapsdistance") after installing the package

Comment: have you tried the `placement` library for distances from Google Directions API? this worked better for me